# Simplification of array terms

Tags: simplifying-expressions, list-manipulation

My $n$th term in an array is an expression, something like $v=\{0,a^2+2,\frac{2ab}{5}-\frac{a^3}4,\frac{2abc}{3}-\frac{a^3}4,...\}$. As the array length increases, the number of variables involved also increase one by one. Now the task is to equate some of these terms in the array to $0$, and find relations among the variables involved. I tried using `Simplify[v[[3]]=0]` for simplifying the third term, which is in vain. How can this be done?

In my problem, **I need to express each variable in terms of $a$** and possibly find one particular command where a series of substitutions can solve the problem of expressing all the variables in terms of $a$. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `v /. Solve[v[[3]] == 0, b]`; however, this does not simplify the second term since there is no dependence on `b` in the second term.

Comment: I would work iteratively, eliminating one variable every time you add another constraint.  However, without a more detail about the form of the problem, it is difficult to make a concrete recommendation.

Comment: Are there higher powers? The powers in your sequence make that the number of possible solutions increases rapidly. Is this really what you want?

Comment: @DanielHuber, number of variables increase just one at  a time, but the powers are not fixed. Was just looking for the array completely simplified in terms of $a$

Comment: @mikado, and in the iteration, what's the command to solve each entry in the array termwise?

Comment: @user74846 Again the powers. I assume you want as a solution: b=b[a], c=c[a,b, ...]. Now if you have powers higher than one, you get multiple solutions. And you see that their number increases rapidly. Or are all variable >0 and you are happy with the real branch?

Comment: @DanielHuber, the variables increase linearly

Answer (score 2):

I assume, according to your information, that all variables, except "a" appear only with exponent 1.
Setting every term in the sequence to 0, you want to express all the terms as functions of a. In this case, the first two term in the sequence do not contribute anything and can be neglected. You can then get expressions for the rest of variables in terms of "a" by (I added an additional arbitrary term to the sequence):

```
v = {2 a b/5 - a^3/4, 2 a b c/3 - a^3/4, a c d/3 + 7 b c};
vars = {b, c, d};
rep = {};
MapThread[#2 /. 
    AppendTo[
     rep, (#2 -> (#2 /. Solve[#1 == 0, #2][[1]]) /. rep)] &, {v, 
   vars}];
rep
```

"rep" gives you the substitution rules for the variables. In this example:

```
{b -> (5 a^2)/8, c -> 3/5, d -> -((105 a)/8)}
```